# change variable value of other instances in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, overlay, statefulwidget

I try to create custom dropdown for my app. And the dropdown can have three duplicate on the same screen. When each dropdown tapped, there is a variable called isDropdownOpened set to true. The case, when one of the dropdown opened then I wan't the others have to set it's isDropdownOpened variable to false again. So, how to change the isDropdownOpened value automatically when other instances of dropdown tapped?

should i use state management like provider, or bloc and cubit? Or even i can do it with setState.

here is the code.

```
class SearchDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchDropdownButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  State<SearchDropdownButton> createState() => _SearchDropdownButtonState();
}

class _SearchDropdownButtonState extends State<SearchDropdownButton> {
  late OverlayEntry _categoryBottomBar;
  bool isDropdownOpened = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (isDropdownOpened) {
              _categoryBottomBar.remove();
            } else {
              Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_categoryBottomBar);
            }

            isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
          });
        },
```

and the instances on a row.

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: const [
    SizedBox(width: 20),
    SearchDropdownButton(text: "Consume"),
    SizedBox(width: 20),
    SearchDropdownButton(text: "Gadget"),
    SizedBox(width: 20),
    SearchDropdownButton(text: "Fashion"),
    SizedBox(width: 20),
  ],
),
```

the complete code : https://pastebin.com/QtfDfXzU

Comment: attach your complete code

Comment: okay then, i worry that the code is too long, i give the pastebin link instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is not specific to flutter (React is same). Basic way to do this is moving `isDropdownOpened` [state to parent stateful widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). Corresponding react tutorial is [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up).

If you want to do this in implicit way then yes, you should use state management library for inter-component state sharing.